# Test (with RSpec) a controller outside of a Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm creating a gem that will generate a controller for the Rails app that will use it. It's been a trial and error process for me when trying to test a controller. When testing models, it's been pretty easy, but when testing controllers, ActionController::TestUnit is not included (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543885/why-dont-rspecs-methods-get-post-put-delete-work-in-a-controller-sp)). I've tried requiring it, and all similar sounding stuff in Rails but it hasn't worked.

What would I need to require in the spec_helper to get the test to work?

Thanks!

Comment: I've brought up this question in rspec-users mailing list, and Aslak Hellesoy said that generally, if you're testing a Rails thing, it's easier to compile the gem, use it in a Rails app and write those tests in the Rails app. While it definitely sounds easier, it feels like it's very broken apart. It will make it brittle when I put this gem out there in the wild.

Comment: Since then, I've opted to use the `dummy` app approach. See http://whilefalse.net/2012/01/25/testing-rails-engines-rspec/

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a working standalone Test::Unit test with a simple controller under test included.. Maybe there's some parts here that you need to transfer over to your rspec code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/test_case'
require 'action_controller'
require 'action_controller/test_process'

class UnderTestController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render :text => 'OK'
  end
end
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw {|map| map.resources :under_test }

class MyTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @controller = UnderTestController.new
    @request    = ActionController::TestRequest.new
    @response   = ActionController::TestResponse.new
  end

  test "should succeed" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this later today and post up how it goes.

Comment: It seems the fundamental difference is that I don't think you can make your test class a subclass of ActionController::TestCase in rspec. In rspec I believe it's automatically inferred based on the describe block. eg. describe SampleController, "on GET index" will look for the SampleController in app/controllers. I hope I'm wrong and this can be overridden!