# framework integration testing within a gem: how to set up rspec controller test for a gem rails integration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems, rspec-rails

This question is NOT about how to test controllers in a rails app.

Developing a gem I want to test if my gem integrates in a rails controller.
So running rspec in the gem root is outside the rails environment.

Now how do I write say a controller test which can use the rspec controller example group helpers like `get` or `post`?

IN particular if I set a metatag `:type => :controller` on an example group , how does rspec set up the rails environment and how can i hook into that in order to say set up routes, etc.

I'd rather not have to set up an entire rails app skeleton mostly empty. But I cannot even find info on how to do that. What is best practice to test a gem integrating to rails app or multiple frameworks.

These sources came closest to what I am after:
[Test (with RSpec) a controller outside of a Rails environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577372/test-with-rspec-a-controller-outside-of-a-rails-environment)
but this is for test unit.
http://railsware.com/blog/2012/01/07/testing-gem-integration-with-multiple-ruby-frameworks/
but this is for capybara which directly hooks in a rails app class.

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a nice minimal example of a rails controller integration test from a gem.
`my_gem`. Assume that you are in a gem root with simple rspec setup (say with `rspec --init`). Then `spec/rails_controller_integration_spec.rb` will look like this.

`rspec/rails` does the necessary requires, [among them `rspec/rails/example`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb) which sets up example group types based on metatags. The metatag `:type => :controller` drives the inclusion of the proper group module `RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup` which provides you with [all the goodies of rails controller specing](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-12-2/docs/controller-specs) as well as [all the goodies of `ActionController::TestCase` like `get/post`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html).

Hope this helps.

What I still don't get is how the Rails environment gets assigned. In particular what if I would like to set up two apps `TestTailsApp1` and `TestTailsApp2`. any advice?

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'my_gem'

require 'rails'
require 'action_controller/railtie' # allows ActionController::Base
# crucial part here:
require 'rspec/rails'
# note that require 'rspec-rails' does not work

module TestRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # app config here
    # config.secret_token = '572c86f5ede338bd8aba8dae0fd3a326aabababc98d1e6ce34b9f5'
    # routes.draw do
    #   resources :models
    # end
  end

  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # setup
  end

end

describe 'My gem' do

  context "in a Rails controller", :type => :controller do

    controller(TestRailsApp::ApplicationController) do
      extend(RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup::BypassRescue)
      # example-specific setup for anonymous controller
      # https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller
      def index
      end
    end

    before(:each) do
      # request needs to be setup to avoid path setting error
      @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
    end

    describe "#index" do
      it "works" do
        get :index
        response.body.should == 'index content'
      end
    end
  end

end
```