# Set Rspec default GET request format to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, functional-testing

I am doing functional tests for my controllers with Rspec. I have set my default response format in my router to JSON, so every request without a suffix will return JSON.

Now in rspec, i get an error (406) when i try

```
get :index
```

I need to do

```
get :index, :format => :json
```

Now because i am primarily supporting JSON with my API, it is very redundant having to specify the JSON format for every request.

Can i somehow set it to default for all my GET requests? (or all requests)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
before :each do
  request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
end
```

Comment: @Erik do you have an alternate suggestion, since it doesn't work in Rspec 3?

Comment: The new Rspec 3 syntax would be much apreciated

Comment: Where do you see the "request" variable?

Comment: Things might have changed in RSpec3 world.

Comment: This works for me in Rspec 3+, request.accept = "application/json"

Answer (score 25):

Put this in `spec/support`:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module DefaultParams
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def process_with_default_params(action, parameters, session, flash, method)
    process_without_default_params(action, default_params.merge(parameters || {}), session, flash, method)
  end

  included do
    let(:default_params) { {} }
    alias_method_chain :process, :default_params
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(DefaultParams, :type => :controller)
end
```

And then simply override `default_params`:

```
describe FooController do
    let(:default_params) { {format: :json} }
    ...
end
```

Comment: This is so nice! Thanks for sharing. And just a hint. Because of #merge used in #process_with_default_params you can still "override" format in your spec to something else than json - to html for example.

Comment: Maybe everything after the action should be defaulted to not be mandatory?

Comment: This didn't actually work for me but this similar solution did: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/13535/The-monkey-patch-to-apply-default-parame

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method alias_method_chain -- is there a fix for that?

Comment: @RonLugge You can look at my answer below.

Answer (score 22):

The following works for me with *rspec 3*:

```
before :each do
  request.headers["accept"] = 'application/json'
end
```

This sets `HTTP_ACCEPT`.

Comment: this works for me with Rails 5.0.1 + RSpec 3.5.2 + JBuilder 2.6.0.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution that

1. works for request specs,
2. works with Rails 5, and
3. does not involve private API of Rails (like `process`).

Here's the RSpec configuration:

```
module DefaultFormat
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    let(:default_format) { 'application/json' }
    prepend RequestHelpersCustomized
  end

  module RequestHelpersCustomized
    l = lambda do |path, **kwarg|
      kwarg[:headers] = {accept: default_format}.merge(kwarg[:headers] || {})
      super(path, **kwarg)
    end
    %w(get post patch put delete).each do |method|
      define_method(method, l)
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include DefaultFormat, type: :request
end
```

Verified with

```
describe 'the response format', type: :request do
  it 'can be overridden in request' do
    get some_path, headers: {accept: 'text/plain'}
    expect(response.content_type).to eq('text/plain')
  end

  context 'with default format set as HTML' do
    let(:default_format) { 'text/html' }

    it 'is HTML in the context' do
      get some_path
      expect(response.content_type).to eq('text/html')
    end
  end
end
```

FWIW, The RSpec configuration can be placed:

1. Directly in `spec/spec_helper.rb`. This is not suggested; the file will be loaded even when testing library methods in `lib/`.
2. Directly in `spec/rails_helper.rb`.
3. (my favorite) In `spec/support/default_format.rb`, and be loaded explicitly in `spec/rails_helper.rb` with

   ```
   require 'support/default_format'
   ```
4. In `spec/support`, and be loaded by

   ```
   Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
   ```

   which loads all the files in `spec/support`.

This solution is inspired by [knoopx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022839/set-rspec-default-get-request-format-to-json/#14623960). His solution doesn't work for request specs, and [`alias_method_chain`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_method_chain) has been deprecated in favor of [`Module#prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-prepend).

Answer (score 7):

In RSpec 3, you need make JSON tests be request specs in order to have the views render. Here is what I use:

```
# spec/requests/companies_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Companies", :type => :request do
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "JSON" do
    it "serves multiple companies as JSON" do
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:company, 3)
      get 'companies', { :format => :json }, valid_session
      expect(response.status).to be(200)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body).length).to eq(3) 
    end

    it "serves JSON with correct name field" do
      company = FactoryGirl.create(:company, name: "Jane Doe")
      get 'companies/' + company.to_param, { :format => :json }, valid_session
      expect(response.status).to be(200)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)['name']).to eq("Jane Doe")
    end
  end
end
```

As for setting the format on all tests, I like the approach from this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623960/1935918

Comment: I thought `config.render_views` was sufficient for getting JSON view responses back.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could add the first answer into spec/spec_helper or spec/rails_helper with this:

```
config.before(:each) do
  request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json' if defined? request
end
```

if in model test (or any not exist request methods context), this code just ignore.
it worked with rspec 3.1.7 and rails 4.1.0
it should be worked with all rails 4 version generally speaking.

Comment: If you change this to config.before(:each, type: :controller), then it won't hit model specs.

Answer (score 2):

Running Rails 5 and Rspec 3.5 I had to set the headers to accomplish this.

```
post '/users', {'body' => 'params'}, {'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'}
```

Thi matches what the example in the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#requesting-a-json-response) looks like:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Widget management", :type => :request do
  it "creates a Widget" do
    headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json",     # This is what Rails 4 accepts
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "application/json" # This is what Rails 3 accepts
    }
    post "/widgets", { :widget => {:name => "My Widget"} }, headers

    expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Rspec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#requesting-a-json-response), the supported method is through the headers:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Widget management", :type => :request do

  it "creates a Widget" do
    headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json",      # This is what Rails 4 and 5 accepts
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "application/json", # This is what Rails 3 accepts
    }
    post "/widgets", :params => { :widget => {:name => "My Widget"} }, :headers => headers

    expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

For those folks who work with request tests the easiest way I found is to override `#process` method in `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` and set default `as` parameter to `:json` like this:

```
module DefaultAsForProcess
  def process(method, path, params: nil, headers: nil, env: nil, xhr: false, as: :json)
    super
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.prepend(DefaultAsForProcess)
```

Comment: I feel like monkeypatching the class is the wrong way to go about this when there's other viable solutions.

Comment: @AndrewKS probably it’s not the best solution but I found it most applicable to my cases as others have some issues with different types of requests, for example get params should be query string, post params should be in the body etc. setting header doesn’t take this cases into account but setting ‘as’ in request just makes the request in most expected way and it relies on builtin behavior

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for this specific case. But what I needed in particular was to be able to pass a `params` hash to the `post` method. Most solutions seem to be for `rspec 3` and up, and mention adding a 3rd parameter like so:

```rb
post '/post_path', params: params_hash, :format => 'json'
```

(or similar, the `:format => 'json'` bit varies)

**But none of those worked.** The controller would receive a hash like: `{params: => { ... }}`, with the unwanted `params:` key.

**What did work (with rails 3 and rspec 2) was:**

```rb
post '/post_path', params_hash.merge({:format => 'json'})
```

Also check this related post, where I got the solution from: [Using Rspec, how do I test the JSON format of my controller in Rails 3.0.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576756/using-rspec-how-do-i-test-the-json-format-of-my-controller-in-rails-3-0-11)

Answer (score -3):

[Why don't RSpec's methods, "get", "post", "put", "delete" work in a controller spec in a gem (or outside Rails)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543885/why-dont-rspecs-methods-get-post-put-delete-work-in-a-controller-s)

Based off this question, you could try redefining process() in ActionController::TestCase from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32395899d7c97f69b508b7d7f9b7711f28586679/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb.

Here is my workaround though.

```
describe FooController do
    let(:defaults) { {format: :json} }

    context 'GET index' do
        let(:params) { defaults }
        before :each do
            get :index, params
        end

        # ...
    end

    context 'POST create' do
        let(:params) { defaults.merge({ name: 'bar' }) }
        before :each do
            post :create, params
        end

        # ...
    end
end
```