# RSpec testing Devise SessionController with Jbuilder view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec, devise

I'm using RSpec for testing a SessionsController I am overriding from Devise in my Rails application:
`class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`

The sign_in method renders a jbuilder view:
`render '/users/sign_in', status: :ok`

I get the expected result when testing the view using `curl`. But I haven't been able to make this work with my specs. I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: post '/users/sign_in', @data, format: 'json'
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template users/sign_in with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

The jbuilder views are working for other specs by using `render_views`. But when I add `render_views` to this spec, I get:

```
`method_missing': undefined local variable or method `render_views' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserEdit:Class (NameError)
```

The difference between the specs where `render_views` works and this spec is the type. It's working here:
`describe SomeController, type: :controller do`

But not on this one:
`describe 'User edit', type: :request do`

It's a request type since I'm testing the API response. As I said, I get the expected JSON view using `curl` from the command line, but it doesn't work in the tests. I must be missing some small detail or doing something completely wrong.

I also tried adding this to Rspec.configure but it didn't change anything:
`config.render_views`

**Edit:**

I must add the test pass when using: `render json: { stuff }.to_json, status: :ok` in the controller's response. This started failing when I refactored this into a jbuilder view.

Regarding the format, I'm using the 'simple_token_authentication' gem and passing this info to each request in the spec:

```
{
  'X-User-Email' => user.email,
  'X-User-Token' => user.authentication_token,
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept'       => 'application/json'
}
```

I had `format: :json` in other tests and didn't make it work:

```
  post '/users/sign_in', @data, format: :json
```

So setting format: :json as a value in the second parameter made things work.

Comment: Could you paste the test that passes and the test that fails? The detail you may be missing (just a guess) is the implicit use of Rspec `subject`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Rspec default GET request format to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022839/set-rspec-default-get-request-format-to-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need setting `render_views` for `request` specs. In fact, the error you're getting right now says that views are actually rendering, it's just there's no correct one for your request type (`html`).

You need to add `format: :json` to your second parameter in your request, like this:

```
@data[:format] = :json

post '/users/sign_in', @data
```