# Could not log "render_template.action_view" event after rails upgrade to 4.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am in the process of upgrading a rails app that mostly serves JSON. The last working version I was able to upgrade to is 4.1. Once I upgraded to 4.2, request specs that produce strange errors in the test log:

```
Could not log "render_template.action_view" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `render_views?' for #<Class:0x007fe544a2b170>
```

Somewhere I read that this is due to rails trying to render a view that isn't present. Before the jump to rails 4, we set `headers['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'` and everything was fine. I read that this isn't working anymore with rails 4. I already tried adding `format: :json`, as suggested here: [Set Rspec default GET request format to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022839/set-rspec-default-get-request-format-to-json/25043739#25043739), which didn't help.

Any help on how to get the specs running again would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out, this error occurs if an include is missing in the rspec config block. Adding

```
RSpec.configure.include RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering
```

fixes that issue.