# How do I set a default format in RSpec controller specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Rails app has the controller with actions which response `html` and `json` formats. In specs I should specify `format: 'json'` for all requests:

```
it 'returns list of entities' do
  get :list, format: 'json'
  ...
end
```

Is there a way to avoid write `format: 'json'` for every example? Something like this:

```
context 'json', format: 'json' do
  it 'returns list of entities' do
    get :list
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Edited the title for search-ability. This is also a potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022839/set-rspec-default-get-request-format-to-json/39399215 - which currently does not seem to have a currently working answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399215/544825 but for controller specs.

Tested on: RSpec 3.8, Rails 5.2.1

This module uses metaprogramming to redefine the `get`, `post` etc methods and a memoized `let` helper (`default_format`) instead of metadata.

It basically just merges `format: default_format` into the arguments and calls the original implementation.

```
# spec/support/default_format.rb
module DefaultFormat
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    let(:default_format) {}
    prepend RequestHelpersCustomized
  end

  module RequestHelpersCustomized
    l = lambda do |path, **kwargs|
      kwargs[:format] ||= default_format if default_format
      super(path, kwargs)
    end
    %w(get post patch put delete).each do |method|
      define_method(method, l)
    end
  end
end
```

And then include this module in your `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb`(if you only have one test setup file):

```
require 'support/default_format'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include DefaultFormat, type: :controller
  # ...
end
```

Usage:

```
context 'json' do
  let(:default_format) { :json }
end
```

I don't think this can be done with example metadata as its not available from within an example (which is where the `get` method is called).