# RSpec `post` keyword arguments add unwanted key to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

When testing the handling of a callback, the `post` should return the contents of the body.

I've tried setting it up using the required keyword arguments:

```
post '/api/v1/callbacks`, body: { foo: 'bar' }
```

I want the params to be `{ foo: 'bar' }` but they're being returned as `{ body: { foo: 'bar' } }`.

Is there a way I can use the keyword args while not adding the unwanted `body` key to the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There in no `body` argument, only `params`

```
post '/api/v1/callbacks', params: { foo: 'bar' }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to pass a whole hash as params, instead of having to specify each value, you can do:

`post '/post_path', params_hash.merge({:format => 'json'})`

See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396862/7724157